# apache pig error while loading the data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I loaded the data on pig using the below command but an error is encountered .
please rectify the error and tell me the solution.

```
swa = load '/home/user/data/emp.txt' using PigStorage(',') as ($0,$1,$2);
```

> error- 2017-08-25 09:15:12,656 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:  
>   mismatched input '$0' expecting RIGHT_PAREN

Comment: The $0,$1 and $2 should not be declared in the load statement. and can be directly used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The load statement syntax is incorrect.You have to specify the field name and data type in the following format.

```
 swa = load '/home/user/data/emp.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (fieldname1:datatype,fieldname2:datatype,fieldname3:datatype);
```

For example,assuming you have 3 fields in your file separated by a comma

```
123,London,21.3
234,Paris,18.6
345,New York,22.7
```

Then you would load this data as

```
swa = load '/home/user/data/emp.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,city:chararray,temperature:double);
```